# Should I have two different variables in one class that represent almost the same thing

Tags: java, variables, state

At first I had a class A that took a list B as constructor argument. This list B was kept within class A in a variable. Another class that used this class A needed the data in list B, but in a different way. So I created a specific object C and had a getSomething() method in class A that on the fly created one of these object C, based on information in the original list B. This worked fine.

Then it turned out that the class that called getSomething() needed a little bit extra information that the original list B did not contain. A small calculation on the specific elements in list B however gave me that information. That information needed to be added to the object C. This calculation is a bit heavy so I do not want to do it on the fly when I create object C in getSomething(). This gave me a problem since I cannot update any elements of object C with this calculated information, since the elements of object C do not exist yet, they are created in getSomething().

How should I solve this the best way. Are there perhaps any patterns?

- Do I in the constructor of class A convert the elements in list B to a list of object C and then discard list B, and then perform the calculation and updates all elements of object C?
- Do I keep both the original list B and a list of object C and have two variables with almost the same information, just presented in a different way?
- Or something else?

Edit: C is not an extension of an element in list B, its more that one or more elements in list B is combined to a C.

Comment: if i understood.. shouldn't C be inherited from A ?

Comment: Can you include a code sample? :P

Answer (score 0):

If you can make adjustments to list B to create list C without losing information that class A needs (in other words if class A can function just fine with only list C)  then yes, calculating this in the constructor and not keeping B seems like a good idea.

If, however, you need the original data aswell, class A can keep both. In case you know which information will be the same in list B and list C, you can give the instance of list C a reference to list B, so that it only has to store the information that differs, and can refer to the information in list B when requested something that didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is probably more confusing than the actual problem.

AFAICT you want a decorated B, where the decorated list is computed at in A's constructor.

Whether or not it's copies of B's objects, or a composited reference to the originals (or something else) depends on your actual needs.